# hamburger menu won't align with main nav menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, hamburger-menu

I'm adding a hamburger menu on the left side of my master header.  I successfully added the hamburger menu but it pushed the title and the navigation menu down.  How can I get them to all align on the master header?

what i want it to look like...
[image]

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8wmn5fjf/

header.php

```html
<?php
/**
 */

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    
<div id="ht-page"> 
<header id="ht-masthead" class="ht-site-header">
<div class="ht-container ht-clearfix">
<div id="ht-site-branding">
    <?php get_template_part( 'hamburgermenu' ); ?> 
<?php 
if ( function_exists( 'has_custom_logo' ) && has_custom_logo() ) :
the_custom_logo();
else : 
if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>
<h1 class="ht-site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
<?php else : ?>
<p class="ht-site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<p class="ht-site-description"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
        
</div><!-- .site-branding -->
<nav id="ht-site-navigation" class="ht-main-navigation">
<div class="toggle-bar"><span></span></div>
<?php 
wp_nav_menu( array( 
'theme_location' => 'primary', 
'container_class' => 'ht-menu ht-clearfix' ,
'menu_class' => 'ht-clearfix',
'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
) ); 
?>
</nav><!-- #ht-site-navigation -->
</div>
</header><!-- #ht-masthead -->
<div id="ht-content" class="ht-site-content ht-clearfix">
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#hamburger-nav-icon').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');
    if (jQuery('#hamburger-menu').css('opacity') == '0') {
      jQuery('#hamburger-menu').css('opacity', '1');
      jQuery('#hamburger-menu').fadeIn(300).css('display', 'table');
    } else {
      jQuery('#hamburger-menu').css('opacity', '0');
      jQuery('#hamburger-menu').fadeOut(300).css('display', 'none');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Header
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

#ht-masthead {
  background: #FFF;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: height 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 38px;
  width: 100%;
}

.ht-sticky-header #ht-masthead {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.ht-sticky#ht-masthead {
  height: 74px;
}

.ht-sticky-header #ht-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  padding-top: 94px;
}

#ht-site-branding {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  transition: padding 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: padding 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.3s ease;
}

.ht-sticky #ht-site-branding {
  padding: 5px 0;
}

#ht-site-branding img {
  max-height: 60px;
  width: auto;
}

.ht-main-header {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 45px 0;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.ht-main-title {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.ht-main-title:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ht-site-title {
  font-family: 'futura_tbold';
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.ht-site-title a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.ht-site-title a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.ht-site-description {
  color: #EEE;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 1;
}

.ht-site-description a {
  color: #333;
}

#total-breadcrumbs,
.woocommerce .woocommerce-breadcrumb {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  color: inherit;
}

.woocommerce .woocommerce-breadcrumb a,
#total-breadcrumbs a {
  color: #000;
}

.woocommerce .woocommerce-breadcrumb a:hover,
#total-breadcrumbs a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.taxonomy-description,
.term-description {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.taxonomy-description p:last-child,
.term-description p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## General
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

.ht-section {
  padding: 60px 0;
  background: #FFF;
}

.ht-section-title-tagline {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.ht-section-title {
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 36px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto 15px;
}

.ht-section-title:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ht-section-tagline {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#ht-page {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Menus
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

#ht-site-navigation {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0;
  transition: padding 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: padding 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.3s ease;
  float: right;
}

.ht-sticky #ht-site-navigation {
  padding: 17px 0;
}

.ht-main-navigation .ht-menu {}

.ht-main-navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.ht-main-navigation li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.ht-main-navigation a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.ht-main-navigation ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  min-width: 200px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  height: 300px;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  -moz-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.ht-sticky .ht-main-navigation ul ul {
  margin-top: 17px;
}

.ht-main-navigation ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 8px;
  border-top: 0;
}

.ht-sticky .ht-main-navigation ul ul ul {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.ht-main-navigation ul ul a {
  text-transform: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #444;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
}

.ht-main-navigation ul ul li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}

.ht-main-navigation ul ul li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ht-main-navigation ul li:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.page-template-home-template .ht-main-navigation .current_page_item>a,
.page-template-home-template .ht-main-navigation .current-menu-item>a,
.page-template-home-template .ht-main-navigation .current_page_ancestor>a,
.home.blog .ht-main-navigation .current_page_item>a,
.home.blog .ht-main-navigation .current-menu-item>a,
.home.blog .ht-main-navigation .current_page_ancestor>a {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ht-main-navigation li:hover>a,
.page-template-home-template .ht-main-navigation li:hover>a,
.home.blog .ht-main-navigation li:hover>a,
.ht-main-navigation .current_page_item>a,
.ht-main-navigation .current-menu-item>a,
.ht-main-navigation .current_page_ancestor>a,
.page-template-home-template .ht-main-navigation .current>a,
.home.blog .ht-main-navigation .current>a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.site-main .comment-navigation,
.site-main .posts-navigation,
.site-main .post-navigation {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.comment-navigation .nav-previous,
.posts-navigation .nav-previous,
.post-navigation .nav-previous {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.comment-navigation .nav-next,
.posts-navigation .nav-next,
.post-navigation .nav-next {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50%;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Hamburger Menu
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#hamburger-menu{
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.95);
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    display: table;
}

.hidden{
    display: none;
    visibility: none;
}

#hamburger-menu ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#hamburger-menu ul li{
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#hamburger-menu ul li:hover{
    background-color: #006973;
    -webkit-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: .15s ease-in-out;
}

#hamburger-menu ul a{
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    color: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 75px;
    padding: 10px 700px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#hamburger-menu ul a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff ;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon {
    z-index: 20;
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 35px 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  background: #bada33;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

/* Icon 3 */

#hamburger-nav-icon span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon span:nth-child(2),#hamburger-nav-icon span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 12px;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 24px;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 8px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#hamburger-nav-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#hamburger-nav-icon.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 8px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="ht-masthead" class="ht-site-header">
<div class="ht-container ht-clearfix">
<div id="ht-site-branding">
    <div id="hamburger-nav-icon">
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
            </div>

        <div id="hamburger-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
            </ul>
</div> 
<h1 class="ht-site-title"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/" rel="home">Site Name</a></h1>
<p class="ht-site-description"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/" rel="home"></a></p>
        
</div><!-- .site-branding -->
<nav id="ht-site-navigation" class="ht-main-navigation">
<div class="toggle-bar"><span></span></div>
<div class="ht-menu ht-clearfix"><ul id="menu-primary-menu-links" class="ht-clearfix"><li id="menu-item-129" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-129"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Item 1</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-139" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-139"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Sub Item 1</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-140" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-140"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Sub Item 2</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-138" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-138"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Sub Item 3</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-137" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-137"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Sub Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-128" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-128"><a href="http://localhost:8888/">Item 2</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-142" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-142"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Sub Item 1</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-143" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-143"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Sub Item 2</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-141" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-141"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Sub Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-132" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-132"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Item 3</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-130" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-130"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Item 4</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-759" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-759"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Item 5</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-135" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-135"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Item 6</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-133" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-133"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Item 7</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-150" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-150"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Sub Item 1</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-149" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-149"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Sub Item 2</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-148" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-148"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Sub Item 3</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-147" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-147"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Sub Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-509" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-509"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Item 8</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-512" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-512"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Sub Item 1</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-510" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-510"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Sub Item 2</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-513" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-513"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Sub Item 3</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-511" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-511"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">Sub Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div></nav><!-- #ht-site-navigation -->
</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

An immediate way to solve this is to add `margin-left: 55px` to `#ht-site-navigation` and change the `padding` of that rule to  `padding: 0 0 15px  0;`:

https://jsfiddle.net/n5rr9usr/2/

But I actually would change a lot more in that code...

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#hamburger-nav-icon').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');
    if (jQuery('#hamburger-menu').css('opacity') == '0') {
      jQuery('#hamburger-menu').css('opacity', '1');
      jQuery('#hamburger-menu').fadeIn(300).css('display', 'table');
    } else {
      jQuery('#hamburger-menu').css('opacity', '0');
      jQuery('#hamburger-menu').fadeOut(300).css('display', 'none');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Header
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

#ht-masthead {
  background: #FFF;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: height 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 38px;
  width: 100%;
}

.ht-sticky-header #ht-masthead {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.ht-sticky#ht-masthead {
  height: 74px;
}

.ht-sticky-header #ht-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  padding-top: 94px;
}

#ht-site-branding {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  transition: padding 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: padding 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.3s ease;
}

.ht-sticky #ht-site-branding {
  padding: 5px 0;
}

#ht-site-branding img {
  max-height: 60px;
  width: auto;
}

.ht-main-header {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 45px 0;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.ht-main-title {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.ht-main-title:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ht-site-title {
  font-family: 'futura_tbold';
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.ht-site-title a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.ht-site-title a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.ht-site-description {
  color: #EEE;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 1;
}

.ht-site-description a {
  color: #333;
}

#total-breadcrumbs,
.woocommerce .woocommerce-breadcrumb {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  color: inherit;
}

.woocommerce .woocommerce-breadcrumb a,
#total-breadcrumbs a {
  color: #000;
}

.woocommerce .woocommerce-breadcrumb a:hover,
#total-breadcrumbs a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.taxonomy-description,
.term-description {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.taxonomy-description p:last-child,
.term-description p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## General
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

.ht-section {
  padding: 60px 0;
  background: #FFF;
}

.ht-section-title-tagline {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.ht-section-title {
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 36px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto 15px;
}

.ht-section-title:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ht-section-tagline {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#ht-page {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Menus
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

#ht-site-navigation {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  transition: padding 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: padding 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.3s ease;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  margin-left: 55px;
}

.ht-sticky #ht-site-navigation {
  padding: 17px 0;
}

.ht-main-navigation .ht-menu {}

.ht-main-navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.ht-main-navigation li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.ht-main-navigation a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.ht-main-navigation ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  min-width: 200px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  height: 300px;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  -moz-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.ht-sticky .ht-main-navigation ul ul {
  margin-top: 17px;
}

.ht-main-navigation ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 8px;
  border-top: 0;
}

.ht-sticky .ht-main-navigation ul ul ul {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.ht-main-navigation ul ul a {
  text-transform: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #444;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
}

.ht-main-navigation ul ul li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}

.ht-main-navigation ul ul li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ht-main-navigation ul li:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.page-template-home-template .ht-main-navigation .current_page_item>a,
.page-template-home-template .ht-main-navigation .current-menu-item>a,
.page-template-home-template .ht-main-navigation .current_page_ancestor>a,
.home.blog .ht-main-navigation .current_page_item>a,
.home.blog .ht-main-navigation .current-menu-item>a,
.home.blog .ht-main-navigation .current_page_ancestor>a {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ht-main-navigation li:hover>a,
.page-template-home-template .ht-main-navigation li:hover>a,
.home.blog .ht-main-navigation li:hover>a,
.ht-main-navigation .current_page_item>a,
.ht-main-navigation .current-menu-item>a,
.ht-main-navigation .current_page_ancestor>a,
.page-template-home-template .ht-main-navigation .current>a,
.home.blog .ht-main-navigation .current>a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.site-main .comment-navigation,
.site-main .posts-navigation,
.site-main .post-navigation {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.comment-navigation .nav-previous,
.posts-navigation .nav-previous,
.post-navigation .nav-previous {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.comment-navigation .nav-next,
.posts-navigation .nav-next,
.post-navigation .nav-next {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50%;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Hamburger Menu
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

#hamburger-menu {
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  display: table;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: none;
}

#hamburger-menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#hamburger-menu ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#hamburger-menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #006973;
  -webkit-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
  transition: .15s ease-in-out;
}

#hamburger-menu ul a {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #fff;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 75px;
  padding: 10px 700px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#hamburger-menu ul a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon {
  z-index: 20;
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 35px 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  background: #bada33;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}


/* Icon 3 */

#hamburger-nav-icon span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon span:nth-child(2),
#hamburger-nav-icon span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 12px;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 24px;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 8px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#hamburger-nav-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#hamburger-nav-icon.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 8px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="ht-site-navigation" class="ht-main-navigation">
  <div class="toggle-bar"><span></span></div>
  <div class="ht-menu ht-clearfix">
    <ul id="menu-primary-menu-links" class="ht-clearfix">
      <li id="menu-item-129" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-129"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/fashion/">item 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-139" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-139"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/fashion/fashion-news/">sub item 1</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-140" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-140"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/fashion/my-looks/">sub item 2</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-138" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-138"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/fashion/outfit-ideas/">sub item 3</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-137" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-137"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/fashion/shopping/">sub item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-128" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-128"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/beauty/">item 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-142" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-142"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/beauty/hair/">sub item 1</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-143" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-143"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/beauty/makeup/">sub item 2</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-141" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-141"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/beauty/skincare/">sub item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-132" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-132"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/living/">item 3</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-130" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-130"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wellness/">item 4</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-759" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-759"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/travel/">item 5</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-135" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-135"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/video/">item6</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-133" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-133"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/shop/">item 7</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-150" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-150"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/shop/my-closet/">sub item 1</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-149" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-149"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/shop/my-picks/">sub item 2</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-148" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-148"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/shop/instagram/">sub item 3</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-147" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-147"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/shop/snapchat/">sub item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-509" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-509"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/more/">item 8</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-512" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-512"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/contact/">sub item 1</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-510" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-510"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/about/">sub item 2</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-513" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-513"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/faq/">sub item 3</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-511" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-511"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/archive/">sub item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="hamburger-nav-icon">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>

<div id="hamburger-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  However, it did not work on my site, and then I realized that my html is different than the one originally posted.  Is there anyway you could help with the new html I posted?